# Early Stopping Perceptron Training

Tags: matlab, neural-network, training-data

Using MATLAB's Neural Network Toolbox I have created a single layer perceptron. I can use the train function to train the neural network. However I either have to set the number of epochs or interactively stop training.
I would like to use a part of my data set as validation and use early stopping to end training and avoid overfitting.

When using the `train` function, I either have to specify the number of epochs or stop training interactively, with my current parameters. How do I stop training using early stopping?

I have attempted to use, without much success the following classification:

```
net.divideFcn = 'divideblock';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100; %70 percent of data used for training
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100; %15 percent of data used for validation
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100; %15 percent of data used for testing
```

Comment: Please how did get the neural network toolbox did you pay for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change :

```
net.trainParam.max_fail = 1;
```

For example? I believe the default value is 6. This is the parameter that stops training when the validation loss didnt decrease for `max_fail` number of epochs.

Comment: I have tried this, but unfortunately it did not resolve my problem.